# More users equals/equal more profit

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I know '**user**' is a countable noun and 'user**s**' is plural. So my logic is that it should be 'equal' but I see many instances that people use 'equal**s**' instead. Are people using it incorrectly or is there some usage I am not aware of?

> More users **equals** more profit, as simple as that.
>
> More users **equal** more profit, as simple as that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The subject of the sentence here is not really "users." It's the entire concept of "more users." The users aren't doing the "equaling." For this reason, "equals" is correct. You could think of an implied gerund being the true subject:

(Having) more users equals more profit.

**Edit:** This is not my contribution, the credit goes to Tᴚoɯɐuo, but it's important enough to add that only some verbs really work with this construction. Verbs that, as Tᴚoɯɐuo said, "go better with existential facts and their consequences or demands. equals, means, leads to, results in, brings, takes, gives, asks for, demands, etc. *A stretch in solitary and no TV gives a man plenty of time to think.*"

Comment: I had to undo my +1.  You were on the right tack before you edited your answer and added the remark about "the proper grammatical structure" requiring the plural verb.  (There being) more users means more profit.

Comment: I suppose you are right. I think it's simply that I probably wouldn't use the structure "more users equals more profit" in very formal writing. I would explicitly state the subject.

Comment: *A package of ramen noodles in the pantry and a few more ingredients means you can quickly and easily round out a dinner in a variety of ways.*

Comment: Okay, I'm convinced. I'll remove my edit!

Comment: I can see it now.  More examples equals better understanding. Thank you, both.

Comment: @whitecap  You have to be careful, though.  A couple of relevant English aphorisms, *"Too many cooks **spoil** the broth"* and *"Many hands **make** light work"*.    The "having" can be, but isn't always, implied.

Comment: @Andrew Good point. Do you think the clue may be in the verb, though? One cook can spoil a broth. Many cooks can spoil a broth. Hands make things. "Equals," on the other hand, kind of needs a concept of numbers. "Means" typically applies to concepts. Anyway, that's my vague concept for a rule of thumb. ;)

Comment: @joiedevivre  I honestly don't know.  I could go either way.

Comment: @Andrew: Why do you have to torture me? Now I have another question that is eating me up. (I am joking) Is there a marker or guidance I can use to distinguish the two different usages?

Comment: @whitecap.  It seems to depend on whether the "having" is implied.  "(Having) Too many cooks **is** a bad thing".  "Many hands **are** helpful."

Comment: @Andew: Okay. I will watch out whenever I encounter this usage and interpret the writer's implication. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew, it seems that "(Having) many hands is helpful" is possible too. ???

Comment: @dan "Having many hands is helpful" is grammatical, but I'd never say "Many hands is helpful." Maybe this construct can never be used with the copula. Maybe, as I mentioned previously, it's because it works best with specific verbs, like "equals" and "means."

Comment: @joiedevivre, if this is the case, I think it's an important point that should be included in your answer above. Otherwise, we learners might think the construct could be used for any verbs.

Comment: @dan I absolutely would change my answer to include it if I were more certain. I'll try to do some research and see if I can improve it.

Comment: You will hear this anywhere you go, in the context of a conversation about having help on a project: *Many hands means you will get the job done quicker*   or *Many hands shares the load*.  The subject is the existential fact of there being many hands.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That is using the verb "means" again, though. Your previous example also used "means." In Andrew's earlier example, "_Many hands make light work_," this construction wouldn't be used. Do you know if it's because of the verb? That's still my best guess. "Means" treats "many hands" as a singular concept. A verb like "equals" makes the numerical comparison important to the idea.

Comment: There are certain verbs which go better with existential facts and their consequences or demands. equals, means, leads to, results in, brings, takes, gives, asks for, demands, etc.   *A stretch in solitary and no TV gives a man plenty of time to think.*